# How to smoothly animate a bound property value from it's old value to it's new value in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

How do I smoothly animate from the previous value of a bound property to it's new value?

Let's say we have the following Canvas and Line.

```
<Canvas>
    <Line 
        Canvas.Top="0"
        Stroke="#887FFF00"
        StrokeThickness="2"
        X1="0" Y1="0"
        X2="0" Y2="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Canvas}}"
        Canvas.Left="{Binding Position}"
        >
    </Line>
</Canvas>
```

The horizontal position of the line is determined by a Position property bound to the Canvas.Left attached property. When the Position changes from say, 100 to 200, I would like to animate the position of the line from it's previous value, smoothly to it's new value.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

By far the simplest way to animate a property smoothly in wpf is to use an animation.

There are a few tricky bits to animations for your requirement though.

You can't bind a "from" or "to" on an animation so this will involve creating an animation in code.

You need a dependency property and hence a dependency object to animate a value.

You could consider making the viewmodel which exposes position into a dependency object. You can then create a new animation in code when you need to animate it and just retain your binding there.

Or... you could define a storyboard as a resource and alter that in code to do your animation.

Like this https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31191.wpf-tips-animating-a-viewmodel.aspx

Maybe you don't fancy making the viewmodel a dependency object.

If you're ok with a bit of "code behind" in your view then that's a dependency object. You could alternatively add a dependency property to your window.  Bind that to Position and then animate the canvas.left of your line or another dependency property the line is bound to.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding to directly the source property using the `{Binding}` syntax in XAML, you could subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event of the view model yourself in the view and animate the property programmatically, e.g.:

```
private void OnViewLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ViewModel viewModel = DataContext as ViewModel;
    if (viewModel != null)
    {
        Canvas.SetLeft(line, viewModel.Position);
        viewModel.PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;
    }
}

private void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "Position")
    {
        double from = Canvas.GetLeft(line);
        if (double.IsNaN(from))
            from = 0;
        ViewModel viewModel = sender as ViewModel;
        if (viewModel != null)
        {
            DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation()
            {
                From = from,
                To = viewModel.Position,
                Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
            };
            line.BeginAnimation(Canvas.LeftProperty, doubleAnimation);
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Canvas Width="100" Height="100" Background="Beige">
<Line x:Name="line"
        Canvas.Top="0"
        Stroke="#887FFF00"
        StrokeThickness="2"
        X1="0" Y1="0"
        X2="0" Y2="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Canvas}}">
</Line>
</Canvas>
```

This is an example of a situation where you want to implement custom *view-specific* logic in the view, and you don't want to do this in XAML. This does not break the MVVM pattern in any way.